# Xcode will not show up on MacOS server Services

Tags: macos-high-sierra

I am using a mac running on High-Sierra, I have installed MacOS server and xcode. On the sidebar of macOS services. Xcode is suppose to be shown like this:

[image]

But on my macOS server, it does not show it.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related with the last upgrade "Xcode 9".

> At WWDC 2017, Apple announce something that made almost every iOS developer smile, session on ‘What’s New in Signing for Xcode and Xcode Server’. It’s hard to explain, how easy it become to perform Continuous Integration for Apple platforms especially iOS and macOS using Xcode 9 and Xcode Server.

More details about WWDC 2017: [Click Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/403/)

**Xcode Server no longer need macOS Server app, it’s now built inside Xcode.**

For continuous integreation, plase following [this](https://medium.com/xcblog/xcode9-xcode-server-comprehensive-ios-continuous-integration-3613a7973b48) link.

Good coding!